# If Donald Trump is so unpopular with black voters, why is he leading in states where there are the highest percentage of black people?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump

According to some [articles](http://time.com/4389251/donald-trump-1-percent-support-poll/), Trump is very unpopular with black voters.

Why is it then that states such as Alabama, Louisiana and Mississippi which have [some of the highest percentage of blacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_by_African-American_population)  are strongly supporting Trump as shown in [many polls](http://www.electoral-vote.com/)?

Comment: Are anti-Trump demographics a majority in any of the states you mentioned? Or pro-Trump? Sorry but this question seems too trivial

Comment: I suspect that the poll numbers may be way off.  98=99% is a hard number to pull off in any direction

Answer (score 7):

Because he is exceptionally popular with whites in those states.  All three voted for Romney in 2012 even though he had one of the lower Republican shares of the black vote (about [6%](http://ropercenter.cornell.edu/polls/us-elections/how-groups-voted/how-groups-voted-2012/)).

Mississippi and Louisiana are first and second in the black percentage of the population.  Alabama is sixth.  It's interesting to look at the three between:  Georgia, Maryland, and South Carolina.  South Carolina remains overwhelmingly Republican (again, whites there like him more often than do whites in more liberal states).  But Georgia has become a marginal state.  And Maryland was and is overwhelmingly Democrat.

It's also worth noting that George W. Bush was only winning about 11% of the black [vote in 2004](http://ropercenter.cornell.edu/polls/us-elections/how-groups-voted/how-groups-voted-2004/).  So Trump's [8%](http://www.nbcnews.com/storyline/2016-election-day/trump-did-better-blacks-hispanics-romney-12-exit-polls-n681386) was not nearly as big a drop as it might otherwise be.  He actually did better than Mitt Romney in 2012 and John McCain in 2008.

Trump also does better with richer voters but better in poorer states.  It's problematic to use statistics on a large group to predict the behavior of a smaller group chosen by a non-random criterion.  The smaller group often has distinctions from the larger group.  In these cases, whites in the Southern states are more conservative than in other states, particularly the Northeast and West coast.

Answer (score 3):

"States such as Alabama, Louisiana and Mississippi which have some of the highest percentage of blacks" are the deep South states that were the core of the "Confederacy" during the Civil War. There are many blacks there, even today, because these were the most "pro slavery" states (among whites) in the earlier period.

In those highly polarized states, the blacks (still a minority) vote one way, and the whites vote the opposite way in greater percentages than elsewhere. Nowadays, that means Democrat for blacks and Republican for whites but just after the Civil War (in the window when blacks could vote) it was blacks for Republicans (Lincoln) and whites for Democrats (the party of the pro slavery candidates).

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, all those states have been [red (Republican) states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_states_and_blue_states) and the fact that those 3 states have some of the highest percentage of blacks doesn't matter that much because blacks don't have the number of registered voters large enough to influence the results.

According to the linked article, [2016 electorate will be the most diverse in U.S. history](http://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2016/02/03/2016-electorate-will-be-the-most-diverse-in-u-s-history/), blacks elegible for 2016 elections are only 27.4 million, which is only 12.1% of 225.8 million eligible voters. If you compare the number with 156.1 million whites (69.1% of total), you can see how big the difference is.

Considering the fact that only 67% of the black eligible voters cast their votes in the 2012 presidential election, their influence on the poll and eventual outcome of the election can't be a deciding factor. In a swing state where no party has a dominant position, their votes could be more important.

Comment: "only 67% of the black eligible voters cast their votes" = globally speaking, "only" might be an appropriate term, but in the US, that's actually an incredibly high turnout percentage and was likely higher than the white eligible voter turnout percentages.

Comment: @blip  2012 had both the highest black turnout (per capita) ever and higher than white turnout (per capita).

Comment: To put some actual data, Wikipedia says 54.9% turnout in 2012. So yes, a 67% is not "only" but actually very high.

Comment: @Rathony we got your point. We're saying "only" is a misleading term here. You probably should just say "Even if 100% voted, their number is not large enough"

Comment: @Rathony "only" infers that it's a low amount. 67% is a high amount. Yes, that high amount is still less than the low amount of white voter turnout...which is your point. You can make your point without using 'only' as a modifier. There's no need for it and only introduces unintentional baggage.

Comment: @Rathony it's *is* a high amount. Voter turnout in this country rarely gets above the 50% mark. That is what we are all trying to explain. If you must use a modifier, you should state "despite the amazingly high turnout rate of 67%"...

Comment: @Rathony That you seem to believe 67% is not an impressively high rate of turnout in this country (and that winning an election is a 'disaster') makes me think you maybe have an agenda (or are not at all familiar with voter turnout in the USA)

Comment: @Rathony as I, and Sjuan, and Brythan point out, we don't *think* 67% is a high rate, it *is* a high rate. All the data makes this very, very clear. I don't know what your agenda is, or if you even have one...I just don't understand why you are arguing against the overwhelming evidence that 67% is quite an anomaly in US voter turnout. Your answer is OK, but the "only" is actually detrimental to your point if we are to understand the point you were trying to make. It implies that it's low. When it's high.

Comment: I also don't understand the correlation you are trying to make between a black candidate should = 100% black voter turnout. It's like saying 100% of eligible voters should turn up when there's a white candidate. Of course, 100% of all voters should always turn up. But that's never been the case in the US...and as stated, is usually very much below the 67% mark.

Comment: @Rathony Are you question the evidence? Have you done any research at all on US election turnouts? And, again, I really don't understand the relevance of Obama with the question. But, whatever.